# Grab text from a text file using Bash

Tags: bash, split

I have a large source code file, I would like to split it into many smaller files.

For this, I would like to insert in the original source code file, certain start line (e.g., `##START`) and certain end line (e.g., s`##END`).

Is there some linux command that searches and then grabs the text between `##START` and `##END` and output it to `stdout`?

Comment: `sed -n '/##START/,/##END/p' file`

Comment: Also related https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15662/187122

Comment: Look at `-A` and `-B` options to `grep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it easy to remember how to see the *"juicy"* parts of a file, define a function in your login profile based on @oguzismsail's comment, like this:

```
juicy(){ sed -n '/##START/,/##END/p' "$1"; }
```

Then you can just run:

```
juicy SomeFile.txt
```